# AWS architecture for create EC2 windows (using AMI), run a my_command.bat, process and terminate EC2 monthly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-batch

I am not sure if this is the right platform to ask this type of question but this is my last hope as I am new to AWS.

I have requirement:

Given: AMI ID (has `my_software` installed, `my_command.bat` created to run `my_software` using CLI).

ToDo (Repeats every month):

1. Create an EC2 instance (Windows) from the given `AMI-ID` (Windows).
2. Run `my_command.bat` file in the instance which runs `my_software` which generates `report.csv` and `log.csv` files.
3. Send `report.csv` to `my_s3_bucket` and log to `CloudWatch`.
4. Terminate the instance. (Stop is not enough).

Please suggest the architecture for the same.

Answer (score 1):

I do similar and it works as follows:

- Create docker image which runs your command (it should log and write to s3 as required).
- Create a batch environment which can pull the image and run the container.
- Create Cloudwatch event to run the job at your desired [cron schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html#CronExpressions)
- The event target is an SQS queue
- Create a lambda function which responds to events on the SQS queue
- The lambda function submits the batch job

Note in theory you can call the Lambda function from the Cloudwatch event rule, but I have to use a queue due to a private subnet.

[Batch Fargate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/fargate.html) is a good fit for this, because it will only use resources whilst your job is running.  If you need to use EC2, ensure that [MinvCpus](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/compute_environment_parameters.html) is zero, so that the instance terminates after it has run.  This can take a few minutes, which you will be charged for, so perhaps Fargate is a better fit.